# How can I hide this bar in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, settings

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for java development. 
But I can't hide this bar from idea settings.
How to hide this bar and what is its name 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **Breadcrumbs** and can be disabled either globally or per the file type (`FreeMarker` in your case):

[image: Breadcrumbs]

Answer (score -3):

It should be the 'Navigation Bar' and it can be hidden and restored from the 'View' menu.